# How to "zero out" and ensure deletion of a string from memory

Tags: c#, string, xamarin, garbage-collection

I understand the main concept of garbage collection, about how once a specific object has no more pointers referencing it, it is "garbage collected".

Does this mean it is freed up but it's value is still available for someone with a debugger/disassembler to read (at least until that address is written to)?

I know with most objects (those implementing `IDisposable` interface in `C#` you can call the `Dispose()` method and be pretty confident that memory can never be accessed again. But what about strings?

I know with garbage-collection (in iOS it's known as `ARC`) once you get to 0 references the object "disposes" of itself. I'm worried that my application (tons of legacy code I took over) has tons of memory leaks with strong references and I do not want *PCI sensitive data* to still live in memory long after I've "set the `String` to `null`". Does setting the string to null put a null terminating character for every char in the string?

Here's some links to some research I've done so far and I think maybe what I'm looking for might be writing/re-writing after I'm done to unmanaged memory:

[Microsoft's Dispose Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

[String Marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings)

[Unsafe Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code)

[System.String Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8)

**TLDR:**

1. I know I can just set the `String` to `null` but I still don't trust that my application has no sensitive data living in memory that can still be referenced by a malicious party.
2. How do you guarantee (from code/unit tests hopefully) a string cannot EVER be referenced again from memory (even from a malicious 3rd party).

Sorry if I'm being paranoid I've just seen so much bad memory management (most of it from a deeply embedded third party framework) in this code base.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring

Comment: I saw that and one of the first things I saw reading those docs was [this](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) . It saw a passage saying it's ok for `.Net Framework` but `Xamarin` uses only `.Net Core` and then compiles down to `iOS` and `Android` binaries at runtime. But perhaps I can still use this class just for the `Dispose()` method? Even if I don't get the benefits of encryption in memory?

Comment: But ty for repointing that link out. Going over it more in depth now

Comment: I think after reading more this answers my question. It seems the limitation is not encrypted in memory (I'm applying my own encryption to the strings, also iOS and Android have relatively robust sandboxes), It was more of a worry that between the time a user enters data and it gets encrypted there are unencrypted copies just chilling there cause of memory leaks. I think the Disposability of this class solves my dilemma. Weird that the docs threw me off of reading the rest by saying `Only compatible w/ .Net Framework`. Misread that it meant only in-memory encryption. that's what threw me off.

Comment: @Jason In the link you provided, there is a blue box that states, *"**Important:**
We don't recommend that you use the `SecureString` class for new development. For more information, see [SecureString shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) on GitHub."*

Comment: @RufusL I saw that too. But do you have an alternative? @barac340 's answer looks promising but a bit more time consuming. I am starting to lean towards `SecureString`. That link shows that the only reason to not use it is for the in memory encryption piece will not work, But I am not worried about that since I do my own encryption. Just need the secure Disposal.

Comment: just some context I legit only need to store these strings long enough to pass it to my encryption function. I just want to make sure there is no trace of the unencrypted value after I pass it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand the main concept of garbage collection, about how once a
>   specific object has no more pointers referencing it, it is "garbage
>   collected".

Almost. The main point is that the object is not garbage collected right away after the last reference to this object was destroyed. After that object is in a pending state and is waiting for garbage collection process to be started.

> Does this mean it is freed up but it's value is still available for
>   someone with a debugger/disassembler to read (at least until that
>   address is written to)?

Yes. As I mentioned above, freed objects are still in memory and wait for GC to start. Because garbage collection is non-deterministic, you do not know precisely when the garbage collector performs its work.
Moreover, you can still obtain a reference to this object (through Finalize method [Finalize override docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.finalize?view=netframework-4.8#overriding-the-finalize-method))

> I know with most objects (those implementing IDisposable interface in
>   C# you can call the Dispose() method and be pretty confident that
>   memory can never be accessed again. But what about strings?

The primary use of this interface is to **release unmanaged resources**. The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a managed object when that object is no longer used. 
[Use the Dispose method of this interface to explicitly release unmanaged resources in conjunction with the garbage collector.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)
Disposing of a managed object doesn't mean that this object is releases - Dispose only change the internal state of this object (for example it frees native bitmap reference), but the object remains the same - it consumes memory, it still can be used, you can call its methods, etc. Only GC removes an object from memory. 
Thus, as a string is a managed object, it is released by GC.

> How do you guarantee (from code/unit tests hopefully) a string cannot
>   EVER be referenced again from memory (even from a malicious 3rd
>   party).

IMO, the solution is to implement your own string wrapper with a dispose-like feature - for example, after you use an instance of this wrapper class and it is no longer needed you can call Free() method and your implementation will rewrite the value of an underlying string in memory (in either safe or unsafe context). But it requires accurate resource management. Also, string rewriting should be called by Finalize() method to ensure memory zeroing after the object was GC-ed.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! Especially from a new contributor and welcome to SO! I think this maybe the method I take. I really like your suggestion. Just one question on "implementing my own string wrapper class". Is subclassing `String` and having my subclass implement `IDisposable` work well enough? I can then do the rewriting in my `Dispose()` method.

Comment: @NSGangster You can't subclass String class, it is sealed (closed for subclassing) to avoid improper use. [link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs) But you can still call internal methods of String class using reflection or using IL code (kinda hack). Take a look on this example: [IL code](https://github.com/vanbukin/Uuids/blob/0e0fb48a77fee944d35fe4fe879d4b0998c01a5e/Uuids.CoreLib/CoreLibInternal.il#L90) [calling from C#](https://github.com/vanbukin/Uuids/blob/0e0fb48a77fee944d35fe4fe879d4b0998c01a5e/Uuids/Uuid.cs#L267)

Answer (score 0):

Accepted @barac340 answer as it was essential in helping me understand memory management in finding my solution.

1. I just use `SecureString`, with a single method that both sends
   it out through encrypted channels and then deletes the SecureString
   passed in.
2. I use the `Marshal` class to rewrite null characters over each
   byte for the the byte length of the `SecureString` starting at the memory address
   of the `SecureString` in unmanaged memory.
3. I then dispose of it, freeing up a bunch of null characters for
   garbage collection. :)

I do want to clarify that it is a known issue on Xamarin.iOS that the memory address of `SecureString` is NOT encrypted on secure string, so even though memory is freed up for GC with use as is, it could still be available in plain text through memory inspection.

I did NOT create a custom class, not because it wouldn't be beneficial for reuse, I just only use this in one spot in this case. And most my "future" use-cases would require disposal of said string after the first "get" of the actual `String` value of `SecureString`. So for now I just put the disposal in the function that uses the string. Specifically because I'm already using `Marshal` to read the `String`, it made sense to write to it after use in the same method.

Should the need arise for a custom class, for what I'm dubbing "ExtraSecureString", 
I will do so.